# Lazyload load binds the images to the wrong view in mulitple listview in same activity

Tags: android, listview, lazy-loading

I am using lazy load class Imageloader to get images from the web server, i have about 3 Listviews in the same activity, for some reason, one of these listviews binds images in wrong way.i want to load my activity then start loading the images for each list view. is there any efficient way for this? Lazyload used to work before... how i can point each view to each image should be loaded? any help would be appreciated :)

```
public class ImageLoader {
    private HashMap<String, Bitmap> cache=new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();
    private RotateAnimation rotate=null;
    private String MainDirectory=".Beirut.com";
    private String Directory=".images";
    private File cacheDir;

    public ImageLoader(Context context){
        //Make the background thread low priority. This way it will not affect the UI performance
        photoLoaderThread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY-1);

      //checking if the main Directory exist?
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),MainDirectory);
        else
            cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
        if(!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();

        //Find the dir to save cached images
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),MainDirectory+"/"+Directory);
        else
            cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
        if(!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
    }

    final int stub_id=R.drawable.refresh_resized_silver;
    public void DisplayImage(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView)
    {
        //Log.e("Image to load",url);
        rotate=new RotateAnimation(0f, 360f, 
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f, 
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f);
        rotate.setDuration(1000L);
        rotate.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);
        rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        //imageView.setBackgroundResource(stub_id);
        imageView.startAnimation(rotate);
        if(cache.containsKey(url)){
            imageView.setImageBitmap(cache.get(url));
            imageView.invalidate();
            imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
            imageView.clearAnimation();
            //Log.e("Animation","Cleared");

        }
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, activity, imageView);
        }    
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView)
    {
        //This ImageView may be used for other images before. So there may be some old tasks in the queue. We need to discard them. 
        photosQueue.Clean(imageView);
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.push(p);
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.notifyAll();
        }

        //start thread if it's not started yet
        if(photoLoaderThread.getState()==Thread.State.NEW)
            photoLoaderThread.start();
    }
    public static Bitmap loadImageFromUrl(String url) {     
        InputStream inputStream;
        Bitmap b;      
        try {           
            if(url.contains(" ")){                 
                url=url.replace(" ", "%20");                   
            }
            //Log.e("Error link",url);
            inputStream = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();             
            BitmapFactory.Options bpo=  new BitmapFactory.Options();             
            bpo.inJustDecodeBounds = true;             
            bpo.inJustDecodeBounds = false;               
            if(bpo.outWidth>400){              
                bpo.inSampleSize = 1;              
                b=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null,bpo );     
            }else{
                bpo.inSampleSize=1;
                b=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null,bpo );
            }
            return  b;     
        }catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);         
        } 
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
    {
        //I identify images by hashcode. Not a perfect solution, good for the demo.
        String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
        File f=new File(cacheDir, filename);

        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null){
            return b;
        }

        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            InputStream is=new URL(url).openStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            //bitmap=loadImageFromUrl(url);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }
    }

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=300;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;

            try{
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);    
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                return null;
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u; 
            imageView=i;
        }
    }

    PhotosQueue photosQueue=new PhotosQueue();

    public void stopThread()
    {
        photoLoaderThread.interrupt();
    }

    //stores list of photos to download
    class PhotosQueue
    {
        private Stack<PhotoToLoad> photosToLoad=new Stack<PhotoToLoad>();

        //removes all instances of this ImageView
        public void Clean(ImageView image)
        {
            for(int j=0 ;j<photosToLoad.size();){
                if(photosToLoad.get(j).imageView==image){
                    photosToLoad.remove(j);
                }else{
                    ++j;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while(true)
                {
                    //thread waits until there are any images to load in the queue
                    if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()==0)
                        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                            photosQueue.photosToLoad.wait();
                        }
                    if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()!=0)
                    {
                        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
                        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                            photoToLoad=photosQueue.photosToLoad.pop();
                        }
                        Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                        cache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                        Object tag=photoToLoad.imageView.getTag();
                        if(tag!=null && ((String)tag).equals(photoToLoad.url)){
                            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad.imageView);
                            Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
                            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
                        }
                    }
                    if(Thread.interrupted())
                        break;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    PhotosLoader photoLoaderThread=new PhotosLoader();

    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        ImageView imageView;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, ImageView i){bitmap=b;imageView=i;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(bitmap!=null)
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
            BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
            drawable.setAntiAlias(true);
            imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
            imageView.clearAnimation();
            //Log.e("Animation","Cleared");
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        cache.clear();

        //clear SD cache
        File[] files=cacheDir.listFiles();
        for(File f:files)
            f.delete();
    }

}
```

and the getview method as follows:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null){
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.videoitem, null);
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
            holder.typetext=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.typetext);
            holder.description=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.description);
            vi.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
        }
        String dprow="";


        //data comes from search list
        if(!data.get(position).getTitle().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            dprow+="<b><strike>"+data.get(position).getTitle().trim()+"</strike></b>"+"<br>";
        }

        String urltoload="http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+data.get(position).getYoutube()+"/0.jpg";
        if(urltoload.contains(" ")){                 
            urltoload=urltoload.replace(" ", "%20");                   
        }
        holder.text.setText(Html.fromHtml(dprow));
        holder.image.setTag(urltoload);
        holder.typetext.setText(data.get(position).getType());
        holder.description.setText(urltoload);

        imageLoader.DisplayImage(urltoload, activity, holder.image);
        return vi;
    }
```

I used notifyDataSetChanged() to refresh the views but its making it so slow. is there any better way to load images in the background for each view by itself!

Answer (score 0):

Use 3 diffrent image_loader (object of lazy loader) to load image for each class. Because lazy list check the old request and the view if exist then cancel it and add request of new image.

Comment: each listview has its own Custom adapter, and image_loader class is initiated in the constructor of this adapter.but iam still getting the same issue...